# How can i create this layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on app which requires layout as described below.

[image]

There are four sections in layout, let's say Layout A, B, C and D.

1. **Layout A** is AppBar and fixed on top.
2. **Layout D** is hidden and appears on scrolling up with some additional effects.

   - On scrolling up **Layout-D** appears from bottom while **Layout-C** starts fading.
   - Everything remains as it is until **Layout-D** completely overlaps **Layout-C**.
   - After **Layout-D** completely overlaps **Layout-C**, on further scrolling up **Layout B** starts scrolling up.
3. Similarly on scrolling down, first **Layout-D** scrolls down then **Layout-B** appears. On further scrolling down **Layout-D** gets hide under and **Layout-C** appears again with fade-out effect.

I already have spent two days and tried using BottomSheet with Coordinator layout but couldn't achieve Exact effects. In addition with BottomSheet scrolling effect isn't that smooth i.e if appears and hide abruptly.

Another thing that i'm thinking to use is Custom behaviour with Coordinator layout but not sure how to proceed.

[image: check].

Comment: Those who down-voting please comment is there anything wrong in question. I'm sure it's not that much easy type question.

Comment: If bottom sheet is not smooth enough, then I think you need to implement touch listeners and combine fade animation with translation of bottom view and manage other B and C views as well accordingly, applayout beahviour can also be used here.

Answer (score 0):

use a fragment with a bottom sheet behavior as follow from the parent activity or fragment  :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomsheetfragmenCoordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorBlackOpacity"
        android:clickable="true"
        >
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomsheetfragmentLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:behavior_hideable="true"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="50dp"
            app:elevation="4dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/bottomsheetfragment"
                android:name="com.example.inslem.it.BottomSheet"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
       </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

bottomsheet fragment :

```
public class BottomSheet extends Fragment {

    public BottomSheet() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }
}
```

and from the parent activity or parent fragment
get the bottom sheet

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    bottomsheetfragmenCoordinatorLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.bottomsheetfragmenCoordinatorLayout);
            behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomsheetfragmentLayout);
            behavior.setPeekHeight(250);
            behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                    switch (newState) {
                        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING:
                            break;
                        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING:
                            break;
                        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED:
                            break;
                        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED:
                            break;
                        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN:
                            break;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
                    Log.i("BottomSheetCallback", "slideOffset: " + slideOffset);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: as i already mentioned in question, I have tried bottom sheet but it does not scroll smoothly and I doesn't help to scroll Layout-B

Comment: in my case it scrolls smoothly, comment your touch event listeners, and try it.